# Does light from incoherent source interfere?

Tags: optics, waves, interference, coherence

We say that for us to observe interference we use coherent source but even if we use non coherent source light should still interfere, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, interference still occurs when light waves from two incoherent sources overlap in space, but the interference pattern fluctuates randomly as the phases of the waves shift randomly. Mathematically speaking, if you have no information about the phase, then you have no technique to predict what you will observe on the screen as the illumination on the screen will be the result of interference of random phases.

Monochromaticity and coherence are only ideal conditions to setup a clear interference pattern. In practice, light is neither $100$% coherent nor incoherent. What we have instead is a [degree of coherence](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031891438802032), $\gamma \in [0,1]$, where $0 \implies$ incoherent and $1 \implies$ coherent. The idea is that the more coherent your light, the sharper (clearer) your interference pattern. However, for completely incoherent light, i.e, $\gamma = 0$, you will observe just illumination.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the pattern fluctuates because if the sources are incoherent then there should be phase difference between the light so shouldn't the pattern be just constant. Like do you mean by fluctuates is that the pattern on the screen changes?

Comment: @KutubkhanBhatiya what I mean is that because the phase shifts of incoherent waves are random, you get a random mix of patterns on your screen, which effectively just looks like a plain illumination. Thus there's very little room to extract any information about the interference.

Comment: This is not a physics related question, but is this all taught in quantum mechanics because I am currently in 12th grade and I have interest in this field so currently I took up like mit ocw courses.

Comment: @KutubkhanBhatiya these things are typically taught in an optics course and not necessarily one on quantum optics. The second part of the answer is something more accessible from an experimental optics course. For more details we can continue this in a [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). Please do mark the answer as correct (the large ✓) if your satisfied with it.

Answer (score -2):

There is an essential difference between EM radiation and sound. Every sound is transmitted by means of the medium (air, water, solid bodies). And, wherever propagating sounds meet, the medium vibrates based on the interference of the sounds.

Not so with EM radiation. Light and all other ranges of EM radiation almost never interfere with each other. There is no medium and intersecting radiation remains unchanged.

At edges, however, all EM radiation is influenced. Behind the edge, there is always a diffraction pattern. This is only prevented if two edges are so close together that EM radiation can no longer pass through at a certain wavelength.

If EM radiation of different wavelengths meets edges, then each wavelength has its own diffraction characteristic. In this respect, your statement that "Does light from incoherent source interfere?" can be answered with yes.

Comment: So if let's say an EM wave is propagating north to south and other is from east to west so will they not interfere. I am sorry if this question is somewhat dumb.

Comment: Yes, exact. And there are not dumb questions :-)

Comment: Oh Okay got it. Thanks a lot